# Hyperlinking a cell with multiple variables to another cell in the same sheet using excel

Tags: vba, excel, if-statement, hyperlink

Is there a way to merge an `IF` and `HYPERLINK` function?

I have my `IF` statement working smoothly but I am having issues with adding the  `HYPERLINK`.

Examples provided below.

```
=IF(A2="Complete Blue Section","Blue Section Link",IF(A2="Complete Red Section"," Red Section Link",""))
```

and a `HYPERLINK` formula. Here's an example:

```
=HYPERLINK("#Sheet6!B44","Blue Questions")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=IF(A2="Blue",HYPERLINK("#Sheet2!B44","Blue Questions"), 
              HYPERLINK("#Sheet3!B44","Red Questions"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that if `A2 = "Complete Blue Section"` that you want to go to cell `B44` on clicking on the cell, then the combined example below should work:

```
=IF(A2="Complete Blue Section", HYPERLINK("#Sheet6!B44", "Blue Questions"), IF(A2="Complete Red Section", " Red Section Link", ""))
```